# Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1472074485: Table 'db.tx_sfregister_domain_model_frontenduser' doesn't exist...?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-9.x

The following error occurs sometimes in the frontend of the TYPO3 9.5.19 production system:
[image: The error in TYPO3 Backend Log]

I have found the following mapping configuration in the third party extension. Does anyone have an idea?
[image: Sf_register Mapping]

Thank you for any hint :)

Comment: Do you have the static template of EXT:sf_register included in your TypoScript template?

Comment: Mappings via `EXT:extension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php`has been introduced in TYPO3 v10.0: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87623-ReplaceConfigpersistenceclassesTyposcriptConfiguration.html For TYPO3 v9 you need to include at least `EXT:sf_register/Configuration/TypoScript/Common/setup.typoscript`

Comment: Yes, I have included the static TypoScript Template in my Main Extension with:
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:sf_register/Configuration/TypoScript/maximal/setup.typoscript">

Comment: Please check via "Template -> TypoScript Objectbrowser" if `config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Evoweb\SfRegister\Domain\Model\FrontendUser.mapping .tableName = fe_users` is set.

Comment: config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Evoweb\SfRegister\Domain\Model\FrontendUser.mapping.tableName =fe_users
is set

Comment: The problem has not yet been solved, are there still ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Repository of sf_register/Classes/Repository and maybe the one of Frontenduser. Try removing the fields related to the database.
Also check the name of the tables in ext_table.sql.